# What does "on the backs of stories" mean?

Tags: meaning

It is from [Crash Course US history](https://youtu.be/QfsfoFqsFk4). It is at 6 minute and 10 second.

> For this Weyler was called "Butcher" in the American yellow press, which sold a lot of newspapers **on the back of stories** about his atrocities.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**"On the back of something"** is an idiom and it [means](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/on%20the%20back%20of):

> because of or on the strength of (something)